# A rigid exponential question

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, lambert-w

This question was given by my friend

> $$x^{x^{20}}=\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}$$

even after applying log this question dosen't simplifies

> $x^{20}$ $ln$ $x$ $=$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ $ln$ $2$

if this question is put in wolfram alpha it gives and if I do a approx form it gives **1.067** how does this came

> $x=e^{\frac{1}{20} W\left(10 \sqrt{2} \ln (2)\right)}$

How to solve this question

Comment: Are u familiar with the Lambert w function?...... Try applying it.

Comment: There must be a typo in the second expression, since 
$\ln(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2})=\ln(2^{\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}})=\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}\ln(2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using by standard techniques, we have

$$\color{red}{\left(x^{x^{20}}\right)^{20}=\left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}} \\\begin{align}&\implies x^{20 x^{20}}=\left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20} \\
&\implies \left({x^{20}}\right)^{ x^{20}}=\left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\end{align}$$

$$\color {blue}{ u(x)^{u(x)}=\left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}}$$

$$\begin{align}&\implies \ln u(x)^{u(x)}=\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\\
&\implies u(x) \ln u(x)=\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20} \\
&\implies \ln u(x) e^{\ln u(x)}=\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\\
&\implies W \left(\ln u(x) e^{\ln u(x)}\right) =W\left(\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\right) \\
&\implies \ln u(x)=W\left(\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\right) \\
&\implies u(x)= e^{W\left(\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\right)}\\
&\implies x^{20}=e^{W\left(\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\right)}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black} {{x=e^{\frac {1}{20} W\left(\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}\right)}}}}}\end{align}$$

**Note that ,**

$$\left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}=2^{10\sqrt 2}$$

$$\ln \left(\sqrt[\sqrt 2]{2}\right)^{20}=\ln 2^{10\sqrt 2}=10\sqrt 2 \ln 2.$$

---

Finally, the real root of our equation is equal to:

$$\large \color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black} {{{x=e^{1/20 ~W\left (10 \sqrt 2 \ln 2\right)}}}}}}$$

Comment: Hint: $\operatorname{W}(10\sqrt2\ln2) = \tfrac52\ln2$.

Answer (score 2):

It happens that this expression
can also be presented in a simple closed form, $x=\sqrt[8]2$:

\begin{align} 
(2^{1/8})^{(2^{1/8})^{20}}
&=
(2^{1/8})^{2^{20/8}}
\\&=
(2^{1/8})^{2^{2+1/2}}
\\&=
(2^{1/8})^{4\sqrt2}
\\&=
2^{{4\sqrt2}/8}
\\&=
2^{1/\sqrt2}
\\&=
\sqrt[\sqrt2]2
.
\end{align}

Comment: the value of x is here found by using Lambert w function no? have you used calculator to find value of x?

Comment: @GeneralMud: Yes, the result is in terms of 
$\operatorname{W}(10\sqrt2\ln2)$,
which in this rare case can be simplified, since the argument 
can be expressed in $u\exp(u)$ form:
$10\sqrt2\ln2 = \ln(2^{5/2})\cdot2^{5/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this problem doesn't have an explicit solution.

Equations of the form

$$x\cdot e^x=c$$

$c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

cannot be solved by simple algebra, but there is a function called [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which can give us approximations.
It is used to solve such and similar equations (like $x\cdot\sin(x)=2$, $x\cdot\coth(x)=-4$).

Comment: Solution in terms of Lambert W function is exact (by its definition).
Exactly as, for example, solution of the form $x=\sqrt2$ is exact.

Comment: @g.kov i know that. What i meant is that there is no more exact way to write $W(2)$, as in if OP wants to express the result without a $W$ function only of compositions of roots of numbers, then more often than not it will be an approximation.

Comment: Of course, you know that. I'm pointing out that statement 
"but there is a function called Lambert W which can give us approximations"
is incorrect, it gives not an approximation, it gives an exact expression,
which can be calculated to any desired decimal numbers.
Also, in this particular case we can simplify this exact expression 
to just $\sqrt[8]{2}$.